# Can a process with a stochastic drift be a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In general, a process with a **deterministic** non-zero drift cannot be a martingale. What if the process has a **stochastic** drift, that has an expectation of zero? Could such a process ever be a martingale?

I am aware that the zero expectation of the stochastic drift is not a sufficient condition for the process to be a martingale, but is there a general mathematical theorem or a result that would prove that a process with **any** non-zero drift  (stochastic or deterministic) cannot be a martingale?

I provide a "counterexample" below (process with a zero-expectation stochastic drift, that is NOT a martingale).

**Question: Could anyone either provide an example of a process with a stochastic drift that is a  martingale or alternatively reference a theorem or a result that shows that all processes with a drift can't be martingales?**

Let: $$X_t:=\int_{h=0}^{h=t}W_hdh+\int_{h=0}^{h=t}1dW_h=\int_{h=0}^{h=t}W_hdh+W_t$$

We clearly have a zero-expectation drift term with:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{h=0}^{h=t}W_hdh+\right]=\int_{h=0}^{h=t}\mathbb{E}[W_h]dh=0$$

And in fact we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_0]=X_0$$

But, $\forall 0< s <t$:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{h=0}^{h=s}W_hdh+\int_{h=s}^{h=t}W_hdh+W(t-s)+W(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right]=\\=\int_{h=0}^{h=s}W_hdh+W_s+\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{h=s}^{h=t}W_hdh+W(t-s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right]=\\=X_s+\int_{h=s}^{h=t}\mathbb{E}[W_h|\mathcal{F}_s]dh=\\=X_s+W_s\int_{h=s}^{h=t}dh=\\=X_s+W_s(t-s)\neq X_s$$

So $X_t$ is not a martingale.

Comment: If $X=Y+Z$ is martingale with $Z$ a martingale and $Y$ a drift, then $X-Z=Y$ is also martingale. But martingale that's of finite variation is? Do you know something telling you that such martingales are of specific type?

Comment: @JanStuller: Do you want a proof in an answer or is Shashi's comment enough? (Although his comment is practically a proof)

Comment: @UBM: if you can post an answer with a proof, I will happily up vote & accept :)

Comment: @Shashi: UBM already provided a great answer. However, I forgot, why the process $A_t:=\int_0^ta_udu$, which he defines below is of finite variation. Could please explain? I think there was a theorem, which states that a stochastic integral with a integrator of finite variation, is from finite variation itself. Is this true? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Literally write the definition of being bounded variation and use triangle inequality.

Comment: @Shashi: Is the following right? In the case that $a_u$ is continuous in $u$:$\sum_i|\int_0^{t_i}a_udu-\int_0^{t_{i-1}}a_udu|=\sum_i|\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}a_udu|\le\sum_i\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}|a_u|du\le t \max_{u\in [0,t]} |a_u| <\infty $ for all $t\ge 0$.

Comment: @user408858 no instead bound it by the full integral of the absolute value. That is finite by definition of being integrable.

Comment: Ok, but this is almost the same, isn't it? $\int_0^t |a_u| du\le \max_{u\in[0,t]}|a_u| \int_0^t du = t \max_{u\in[0,t]}|a_u|$. But, of course, if $a_u$ is integrable, then $\int_0^t |a_u| du <\infty$ would be a bound, too.

Comment: An integrable function need not to be bounded. What you are using does not always work, while the integral bound does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will prove it for an Ito process of the type
$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^ta_udu + \int_0^tb_udW_u, \quad 0 \leq t \leq T. \tag{1}$$

We will need the following two theorems.

**Theorem 1.** Let M and N be local martingales. Then the sum $M+N$ is also a local martingale.

**Theorem 2.** Let $c \mathscr{M}_{0,loc}$ denote the space of continuous
local martingale that starts at zero. Let $M \in c \mathscr{M}_{0,loc}$ be of finite variation. Then $M \equiv 0$ a.s.

**Answer:** Let $X$ be a continuous local martingale of the type SDE(1). Then the drift must be zero.

Proof.
We know the process $\int_0^t b_udW_u, 0 \leq t \leq T,$ is a continuous local martingale. Then the process
$$A_t := \int_0^ta_udu= X_t - X_0  - \int_0^tb_udW_u, \quad 0 \leq t \leq T $$
is a sum of continous local martingales and, by Theorem 1, is also a continuous local martingale. Also, note that $A_0 = 0,$ so $A \in c \mathscr M_{0,loc}^2.$  But the process $A$ is of finite variation, so by Theorem 2, must be zero. This is the same as saying that $\int_0^ta_udu=0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq T.$ Since this integral is defined path by path, by elementary calculus we have that $a_t = 0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq T.$